# Unable to start service with Intent { flg=0x4 (has extras) }

Tags: php, android

I want to insert to PHP from Service. But i've got error something like this :

```
Unable to start service skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.altitudeSurvey@366d624d with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=skripsi.ubm.studenttracking/.altitudeSurvey (has extras) }: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This is my code :

```
public void insert() {
        String time;
        SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        Calendar calendars = Calendar.getInstance();
        time = dayFormat.format(calendars.getTime());
        try {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost("http://studentstracking.hol.es/altitudeSurvey.php");
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("baro", value));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jam", time));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
            Toast.makeText(altitudeSurvey.this, "Response from Server : " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data has been Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This method is inside service. Could you help me how to resolve this ?

Comment: you can't do network operation on main thread. Better use `AsyncTask` to do network related operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this  `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` which means you are calling insert() method from your oncreate . You need to use `AsyncTask` Which will save you from this exception.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         insert()
         return result;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

     }
 }
```

Start asyncTask like this

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Error:**

> Unable to start service
>   skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.altitudeSurvey@366d624d with Int

From error i can see that you are running network operation on main thread. You can not run Network Operations on your application's Main thread.

Either you have to create asynctask or thread to run network operation in background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Write this method inside an asynctask . It will work perfect.